# Get function's this binding

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-2016, ecmascript-next

Given a function,

```
function main() {
  // some logic
}
```

Lets assume the function `main` is bind with `const obj = { name: "John Doe" }`
like `const fn = main.bind(obj);`

Now the question is, Is there a way to get the `fn` function binding?
Note: i know binding can be accessed using the `this` keyword inside the `main` function but is there any way to access `this` value outside the context. is there any magic (hypothetical) method like `fn.getContext()`.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: No, there isn't, since functions are usually not bound to any object, binding the this value doesn't create new properties to function, `bind` just creates a new function wrapping the function call to that newly-created function.

Comment: @Teemu: At least [according to the spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-boundfunctioncreate), the new function object does have an internal reference to the bound value. But that value is not exposed through any user facing API.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, the internal property is assigned to _the new function object_, I assume you can't access that object directly in JS, a reference still refers (seemingly?) to the original function.

Comment: @Teemu: We might be talking about different things. `.bind` returns a new function object, and that's the object that has the internal BoundThis slot (thanks Bergi). So you can access that function object but you can't access the internal slot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there is not. While [the new function object](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/#sec-bound-function-exotic-objects) has an internal `[[BoundThis]]` slot, that slot is not accessible via a user-facing API.

Comment: thank you, but i will continue my search. i will accept the answer in near future when i get exhausted.